# Make a username from a full name using first initial and last name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, string-concatenation

I'm trying to use Excel to create unique usernames using a person's first initial and last name. My current table cells follow the format:

firstname middlename (possiblesecondmiddlename) lastname

How would I write a formula to create this username?

Comment: in cell E1 =left(A1, 1) & D1, however this will do no checking of duplicates etc (also assuming all first names are in col A and all last names are in col D).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is that all in one cell? If so then with data in A1 try this formula in B1

`=PROPER(LEFT(A1)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99)))`

If you want a limited number of characters, e.g. 7, add another LEFT function

`=LEFT(PROPER(LEFT(A1)&TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))),7)`

Answer (score 4):

This is how I did it:

```
=CONCATENATE(LEFT(G2,1),H2)
```

With `G2` being the column that I have the first name in and `H2` being the column with the last name.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a structure as follows:

John Smith = John.S

Used the following formula (could easily be reversed if you want J.Smith):

```
=CONCATENATE((C2), ("."), (LEFT(D2, 1)))
```

Where `C2` is first name and `D2` is last name.

Answer (score 0):

If name appears as `[Kent, Clark B]` in one cell.

I used the following formula to get `"ckent"`:

```
=IFERROR(LOWER(MID(E2, FIND(" ", E2, 1) + 1, 1) & LEFT(E2, FIND(",", E2, 1)-1)), " ")
```

Where `E2` will be the name cell.